# Test Android App From Android Studio In Ubuntu Studio

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

I'm trying to run/test apps created in Android studio. HAXM installer isn't compatible with Linux so I can't use that. I tried the hardware option but this code
"In the build file.....
    android {
      buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }"
from https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html is incorrect (mismatched {}), this may or may not be relevant to the issue?
I can't get Android Studio to recognise my device, I have enabled USB debugging, I have followed the directions to "Set up your system to detect your device" (same page as code above). What am I missing/doing wrong? I'm not  sure about ARM, what is it? can I use that?

Comment: I still haven't found an answer to this but I have found a workaround. I use AirDroid to connect my phone to my pc then build the app in Android Studio and install it on my phone through AirDroid. This does enable testing but not debugging so I would really like a solution.

Comment: I discovered this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=ubuntu&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=-id&id=196866 by chance so changed the platform tools to ver 23.01 and can now use my device to test my app from Android Studio.